# Cloudflare Workers with almost same routes

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I have two routes, track and album

Album

```
https: //mydomain.com/albums/album/ckzz0lo31882850tnsk1qv9awq
```

Track

```
https: //mydomain.com/albums/album/cl018v3uh930220tns5ny4ckde/track/cl0191x11930980tnsx045futm
```

1. I create a worker for tack, track_worker and create the routes for track_worker.
   Route name mydomain.com/albums/album/*
   It is working as expected.
2. I create a worker for album, album_worker and create the routes for album_worker.
   Route name mydomain.com/albums/*
   It is not working.All the route are pointing to track_wroker.

I think that worker service treated it as same route.

May I know how to create a route in CloudFlare rote for above two url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for request url

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
    const url = new URL(request.url)
    // detect track
    if (/album\/.*?\/track/.test(url)) {
        return responseForTrack
    }
    // detect album
    else if (/album/.test(url)) {
        return responseForAlbum
    }
    else{
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. So just use one worker service and check the url. Thanks.